# Measuring Application Performance (Hosted on IBM WebSphere)

Tags: java, performance, websphere, metrics, connectivity

I'm going to start by admitting that I have little experience in this domain outside of measuring response times using Chrome Developer Tools.

I need to provide baseline performance measurements for a web application that is hosted in WebSphere. This is a Java-based web app, and is primarily accessed from mobile devices (iPhones, used in areas with varying connectivity).

My management wants response times for specific actions and/or pages in the app I worked on. What is the best way I can capture this data? Ideally, I'd like to be able to seperate response times for different pages in the app, and also by user session (so that we can isolate different users with different levels of connectivity).

Can this be done from WebSphere? Or does this need to be completed on the client end? I've found WebSphere's PMI module, however I don't know if this will allow me to isolate stats based on specific users and user actions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get a realistic view of the performance that mobile users of the web app will experience, you probably should use a mobile device test framework. I have never used such tools, but Dr Google returns a bunch of helpful-looking pages when queried with "mobile device performance testing tools". :-)

As you mentioned, WebSphere PMI provides many types of measurements about the performance of various aspects of the application server:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rprf_dataorg.html

including measurements specific to web applications, with some average response time metrics:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter10.html

But those measurements will generally be aggregated at some level much higher than individual users or user sessions, since they are intended to provide information about the overall performance of the system.

Also measurements taken in the app server will not include the transport time for the request and response to travel between the mobile device and the app server, or the time for the response to be rendered and displayed by the mobile device.  So those metrics will not reflect the actual user experience.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, it seems WebSphere's performance stats are not what I am looking for... you've steered me in the right direction of approaching this from client side.

I have done some reading on RUM (real user monitoring), and the entire concept of injecting javascript into the app itself that monitors user actions and javascript DOM events. Specifically, Google Analytics was actually mentioned as a possible, pre-built solution for this. As stated, I need to track users, what they are doing, and how long the requests take until the DOM is ready.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry but the mobile user stuff is really out-of-scope for me, I do not have any useful info to share in that area.